# Active class is not working in node+express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I created a simple navbar and a form. Now I want my navbar to show the current  active tab and change its color to yellow or any default color. But somehow it is not working. Here is my code

**main.pug**

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
    head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
        link(href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous")
        link(rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com")
        link(href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet")
        link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/add-product.css")
        title #{docTitle}
    body 
        nav.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-light.bg-dark
            a.navbar-brand(style="padding-left:30px;font-size:2rem;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;color:white;font-weight:bold;" href="#") Node.Js 
            button.navbar-toggler(type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation")
                span.navbar-toggler-icon
            .collapse.navbar-collapse(id="navbarNav")
                ul.navbar-nav
                    li.nav-item
                        a.nav-link(style="padding-left:30px;font-size:1.3rem;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;color:white;font-weight:bold;" href="/shop", class=(path==='/shop' ? 'active' : '')) Shop
                    li.nav-item 
                        a.nav-link(style="padding-left:30px;font-size:1.3rem;font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;color:white;font-weight:bold;",href="/add-product" class=(path==='/add-product' ? 'active' : '')) Product
        block content
```

**shop.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const myproduct = require('./data');
const path = require('path');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const router = express.Router();
router.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
router.get('/shop', (req,res,next)=>{
    res.render('home', {docTitle: 'Index', prods:myproduct.products, path: '/shop'})
});
exports.routers = router;
```

**data.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const products = [];
const path = require('path');
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/add-product', (req,res,next)=>{
    res.render('add-product', {docTitle: 'Add Product',  path: '/add-product'})
});
router.post('/product', (req,res,next)=>{
    products.push(req.body);
    res.redirect('/add-product');
});
exports.routers = router;
exports.products= products;
```

Comment: ok so i have to remove bold property lemme try it out

Comment: @trincot  i removed bold property but still it is not changing color

Comment: I don't see any edit on your post, so I went ahead and removed the bold (double asterisk) for you.

Comment: brother u edited post thats good but do u have any solution of my problem?

Comment: No, as I don't know this technology. To draw the attention of people that do, you should add the relevant tags, like `express` and `pug`.

Comment: @trincot alright thanks brother